# how can i resolve 'element not intractable' error

Tags: python, html, selenium

enter code hereHere I am trying my hands on web automation using selenium-Python. All that I am trying to do is open the desired website, wait for 0.5 seconds and then input the desired text in the search box and click it.
I am trying this on 'geeksforgeeks.org' website. I am very amateurish in these topics so please guide me.

html code for the search box

```html
/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/ul[2]/li[1]/form/input
```

html for the click option

```html
//*[@id="gcse-form"]/button
```

and my code

````
driver.implicitly_wait(0.5)
driver.get("https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/")
element=driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/ul[2]/li[1]/form/input').send_keys('python')
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(element)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="gcse-form"]/button').click()```

this is throwing me 'Element not interactable exception'
kindly help me
````

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this xpath instead?

```
//*[@id="gcse-form"]/button/i
```

Comment: I tried this as well but still it throws me an error!